STM32H562RG Simpler SPI transmission
I measured my SPI transmission takes ~600 CPU cycles @ 250MHz, so it's about 2,5us to transmit 2x 8-bit array.
I'm using HAL (cube IDE). How can I speed it up? I need to make 4 transmissions like this, so it's ~10us. I need it to work with I2S, so it consumes half of sample time only for SPI transmissions... SPI runs @ 31MHz and I can't speed it up bacause of periphera's speed (two 74HC595 ICs in series).
I'm using STM32H562RG; SPI3, only transmit mode on pins PB3 and PB5.
This is my SPI config (of course SPI is disabled in CUBE IDE):
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_I2SEx_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hi2s1, txBuf, rxBuf, 2);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim15);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim17);

  //DWT
  CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;
  DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
  DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk;

  //SPI3
  //Enable SPI3 clock
  __HAL_RCC_SPI3_CLK_ENABLE();
  
  //Set PB3 & PB5 as alternate functions
  GPIOB->MODER  = ( GPIOB->MODER  & 0b11111111111111111111001100111111 ) | 0b00000000000000000000100010000000;
  
  //PB3 (SCK) as AF6, PB5 (MOSI) as AF7
  GPIOB->AFR[0] = ( GPIOB->AFR[0] & 0b11111111000011110000111111111111 ) | 0b00000000011100000110000000000000;
  
  //MBR = /2 prescaler, DSIZE = 8-bit
  SPI3->CFG1 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000111;
  
  //AFCNTR = 1, CPOL = 0, CPHA = 0, MSB first, SPI as master, Motorola protocol, simplex transmitter, no pin swap
  SPI3->CFG2 = 0b10000100010000100000000000000000;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

Transmit function is used like this:
void writeRam ( uint32_t address, int32_t value )
{
    address *= 2;
    (void)transmit( ( address >> 8 ) & 0xFF );
    (void)transmit( address & 0xFF );

    (...)
}

And the transmit function:
void transmit(uint8_t data)
{
    SPI3->IFCR |= BIT(3);   // Clear EOT flag.
    SPI3->IFCR |= BIT(4);   // Clear TXTF flag.

    SPI3->CR2 = 1;          // Set transfer size = 1.
    SPI3->CR1 |= BIT(0);    // Enable SPI
    SPI3->CR1 |= BIT(9);    // Transfer start.

    SPI3->TXDR = data;      // Load FIFO.

    for ( uint32_t x = 0; x < 128; x++ )
    {
        asm volatile ("add r0,r0,1":::"memory");
        asm volatile ("sub r0,r0,1":::"memory");
    }   
    
    while ( !( SPI3->SR & BIT(3) ) );   //stuck here :(

    SPI3->CR1 &= ~BIT(0);     // Disable SPI
}

I've read I can make SPI working on the registers only, but it doesn't work. I've also checked the errata for this uC and there is some problem with EOT detection, but I do both workarounds and still nothing. So, first I tried to set APB1 to 62.5MHz (/4 prescaler) and set SPI frequency to 31.5MHz (/2 prescaler) to decrease ratio betweend PCLK and SPI frequencies and added some delay.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do (or what the problem is) but if you want maximum performance from your SPI peripheral you should probably use DMA.

Well, the problem is in HAL_SPI_Transmit function - it's slooow. It takes about 2,4us to transmit 16 bits @ 31,25MHz. Theoretically it should be ~512ns (16/31.25MHz). I'm trying to make SPI work without HAL, on registers only, but it doesn't work. It stucks at waiting for EOT flag and it doesn't transfer anything. DMA won't help in this case.

It doesn't work is probably you didn't config the MISO line, even you don't use the MISO, it doesn't mean the SPI peripheral doesn't use it internally. SPI clock-out one bit and at the same time it clock-in one bit via the MISO

But when I'm using HAL, I don't use MISO too and it's working... I'm using simplex transmit mode. Btw, I don't have any pin left for MISO.

Check the output at SCK with a scope. Can you see the correct SPI clock frequency during a transfer there? Are there any unexpected gaps between SPI frames?
